# Sorting huge XML files

Tags: xml, xslt, external-sorting

I have 2 huge XML files (4-5 Gb each). XML format is as follows:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <id/>
    <elements/>
    <elements/>
    <elements/>
  </item>
</root>
```

I need to compute whether more `<items>` have been added or modified! For this I am planning to sort the two files and then proceed from there. To sort, I have following two approaches in mind.

1. Convert XML files to other format and perform external sort.
2. Sort using XSLT: I am not sure whether it could be done for such huge files.

I would like to know which of the two approaches is feasible for the problem.

Or if there is a better approach to tackle the problem.

EDIT: I cannot load the entire file on disk, So using "diff" or "bdiff" is not an option.

Comment: Great question!
Was looking for the answer myself!

Comment: If you have a 64-bit OS and a computer with 12 GB or more of RAM then sorting with XSLT might work.

Comment: @Martin Honnen No. I need to make it work for lower hardware specification as well. Otherwise I could have used "diff" on linux. Can you please elaborate on any other methods that can serve the purpose ??

Comment: I am not familiar with XML databases but in theory you should be able to insert a file into an XML database and then query and sort it with XQuery http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-order-by-clause or even XSLT (as long as the database like MarkLogic offers XSLT in addition to XQuery).